# Random increment in python

Tags: python, random, increment

a beginner here, how do i phrase it in python, "in case of a tie,randomly increment one of the two elements?"? 
from python i get SyntaxError: can't assign to function call. any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
if pl1_vote == 2 and pl2_vote == 2:
    random.sample(pl1_vote, pl2_vote) += 1
```

Comment: That makes no sense @DeveshKumarSingh — x will just be `2` in either case. If won't effect either variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it simply explicitly as so:

```
if pl1_vote == 2 and pl2_vote == 2:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        pl1_vote += 1
    else:
        pl2_vote += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track - I can see that you were trying to go for a data-driven approach. However, by virtue of the fact that your votes exist as two separate variables, you're kind of resigned to doing something like this:

```
from random import choice

pl1_vote = 2
pl2_vote = 2

if pl1_vote == pl2_vote:
    if choice([True, False]):
        pl1_vote += 1
    else:
        pl2_vote += 1
```

A data-driven approach would incorporate the votes in some kind of collection. Here's one way:

```
from random import randint

player_votes = [2, 2]

if player_votes[0] == player_votes[1]:
    player_votes[randint(0, len(player_votes)-1)] += 1
```